# Exclude slf4j from different third libraries

Tags: java, logging, solr, intellij-idea, slf4j

In my project I'm using Solr 4.10 (as separate artifact), Tika 1.6 and Tomcat 7.
Solr require to put logging library in tomcat7_dir/lib. Tika also have slf4j library. So on project starting I get multiple binding warning:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/.../apache-tomcat-7.0.39/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/.../out/artifacts/war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/.../out/artifacts/war/WEB-INF/lib/tika-app-1.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

How can I remove unnecessary libraries from loading in Intellij Idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved this small problem:

1. Remove *org/log4j* from tika's jar (just opened by WinRar and removed this folder).
2. In *tomcat/lib* put *slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar*, *slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar* and *log4j-1.2.17.jar*.
3. Project Settings (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), Modules, Dependencies tab -> add jars or directories, select *slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar* from *tomcat\lib* and set **Provided** scope.
4. Also be sure that in your artifact you don't have this libraries

Answer (score 2):

In that case you should keep the slf4j.jar in the tomcat/lib, and remove all other slf4j jars.
In eclipse, a web project can be configured to use a set of jars at compile time(so your project compiles) but are not packaged inside the war. IntelliJ should be able to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for response, but I'm using Intellij Idea and don't have .pom file.
In Project Settings, Tab Dependencies I added libraries (log4j, slf4j-api, slf4j-log4j12) from tomcat_dir/lib. And set excluded for slf4j from tika. But again warnings appears. Intellij copy libraries from tomcat_dir/lib to output folder in compilation phase.